# PHP: declaring the class properties separating them by commas

Tags: php, properties

I know it is common to declare variables in JavaScript separating them by commas. Is it a good practice to declare properties by enumerating in the php language? Example:

```
class Animals {

    public 
       $_dog, 
       $_cat,
       $_bird,
       $_cow,
       $_goat,
       $_drunkard;

    ...

}
```

Comment: I makes no difference. They are declared separately in most PHP code I have ever read, but if you prefer to do it like this then knock yourself out.

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen, I understand your huge experience in self-injuring, but I must decline your suggestion.

Comment: It is just [a saying](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+yourself+out). It means "go for it".

Comment: Translation problems might be curious :)